# VS Code - pylint is not running

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint, vscode-python

I have a workspace setup in VS Code where I do python development.  I have linting enabled, pylint enabled as the provider, and lint on save enabled, but I continue to see no errors in the Problems panel. When I run pylint via the command line in the virtual environment i see a bunch of issues - so I know pylint works.  I am also using black formatting(on save) which works without issue.  I have tried using both the default pylint path as well as updating it manually to the exact location and still no results.  When I look at the Output panel for python it looks like pylint is never even running (i.e. I see the commands for black running there but nothing for pylint).

My pylint version is 2.4.4 and VS Code version 1.46

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: For anyone still experiancing this. If you're using the vscode pylint add-in, Id' recommend switching to the `output` window and selecting `Pylint` from the dropdown. In the past I've had all sorts of errors such as using `True` rather than `true` in my  `pyproject.toml` which caused pylint to log an error and terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
"python.linting.enabled" : true
"python.linting.lintOnSave" : true
```

to your `settings.json`

Comment: They are already enabled in my preferences at the user, workspace, and folder level.  Why would it make a difference if i do it in the preferences vs settings.json?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the newer version of python extension [see here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12285#issuecomment-645875667).

For now you can either wait for the fix to arrive, use jedi language server or install previous version of the extension

Answer (score -2):

1. Uninstall Python Extension
2. Reinstall Python Extension
3. And with that there will will be one more extension of "Python Extension" named - "PYLANCE" don't forget to install that too.
4. Reload VS Code

DONE !!